# What does the -J option mean in jstat?

Tags: java, jstat

I'm learning some JVM tools like jstat, jmap, jtack, etc. When I type `jstat` in the commandline, it responds with the following messages:

```
Usage:
    jmap [option] <pid>
        (to connect to running process)
    jmap [option] <executable <core>
        (to connect to a core file)
    jmap [option] [server_id@]<remote server IP or hostname>
        (to connect to remote debug server)

where <option> is one of:
    <none>               to print same info as Solaris pmap
    -heap                to print java heap summary
    -histo[:live]        to print histogram of java object heap; if the "live"
                         suboption is specified, only count live objects
    -permstat            to print permanent generation statistics
    -finalizerinfo       to print information on objects awaiting finalization
    -dump:<dump-options> to dump java heap in hprof binary format
                         dump-options:
                           live         dump only live objects; if not specified,
                                        all objects in the heap are dumped.
                           format=b     binary format
                           file=<file>  dump heap to <file>
                         Example: jmap -dump:live,format=b,file=heap.bin <pid>
    -F                   force. Use with -dump:<dump-options> <pid> or -histo
                         to force a heap dump or histogram when <pid> does not
                         respond. The "live" suboption is not supported
                         in this mode.
    -h | -help           to print this help message
    -J<flag>             to pass <flag> directly to the runtime system
```

**The question is that I'm confused with the option -J.**

```
-J<flag>             to pass <flag> directly to the runtime system
```

When I type `jstat -J-version`, it says

```
java version "1.6.0_22"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_22-b04)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 17.1-b03, mixed mode)
```

What does this option used for and what does "flag" mean exactly?

Comment: Have you considered consulting the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/share/jstat.html)?

Comment: @EJP I think it's pretty obvious he did read the documentation as it is well documented in his question.

Comment: @EJP  I thought the help message 'to pass <flag> directly to the runtime system' is the official explaination to this option,but I don't understand this.So I searched the google with keyword 'pass <flag> directly to the runtime system' rather than 'jstat', as a result I gotta nothing valuable.It's pretty clear after reading the documentation referred by EJP,-J just means javaOption.Much Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Oracle online documentation about [`jstat`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/jstat.html) is more clear:

> -JjavaOption
>
> Passes javaOption to the Java application launcher. For example, -J-Xms48m sets the startup memory to 48 MB. For a complete list of options, see java(1).

This option is used to pass Java option to the runtime JRE, like setting memory sizes. The list of possible options can be viewed [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/java.html#BABHDABI).

Comment: Thanks.It's very clear after I read the Oracle Docs.I searched the google with keyword 'pass <flag> directly to the runtime system' rather than 'jstat', as a result I gotta nothing valuable.

Answer (score 2):

It means that it passes that flag through to the child JVM process that jstat invokes.

For example, `jstat -J-version` effectively invokes:

```
java -version
```

which has the effect of printing out the JVM version.